# Strange symbol appears in GtkTreeView

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, gtk

I am writting log viewer with GTK for Windows. I use GtkTreeView widget to display log records. It contains 3 columns: date & time, event source, event text. For any reason, in event time column strange symbol appears:

[image]

I used debugger watch window to see string value, and it doesn't contain any extra characters that can result in this strange symbol appearence.

What are possible reasons of such tree view behavior?

Comment: It looks like the reason was Glade bug. I recreated model with Glade (removed it and added it back), and now this strange symbol disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

All text used in Gtk+-2.0 widgets needs to be in UTF8 encoding.Text in plain ASCII is automatically valid UTF8, but as soon as you have special characters that do not exist in plain ASCII (usually characters that are not used in the English language alphabet), they need to be in UTF8 encoding.Otherwise you may get what you are getting now.

Comment: Hi, I understand, but for date & time which contains digits, hyphens, spaces and colons only, UTF8 is the same as ASCII, and I saw in watch window that it really doesn't contain any extra non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is something weird but gtk use to have this problem if you do not use glib library functions. You need to handle all of the strings with this functions. This could be a rendering issue.

for paths you use `g_path_get_basename(path);`

for dirs you use `g_path_get_dirname (path);`

for date and time use some of this docs [gtk date and time](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.68/glib-Date-and-Time-Functions.html)

so it can be displayed properly in the treeview